# Nokogiri: Finding and XML element then adding child elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

I have an xml document and I want to add child elements under the element with the name 'InitgPty' and I'm attempting to do so as follows:

```
filename = "#{payment.updated_at.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.xml"
file_contents = File.read("#{filename}")

doc = Nokogiri::XML(file_contents)

initgpty = doc.at_xpath("//InitgPty")
first_id_tag = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "Id", doc
initgpty.add_next_sibling(first_id_tag)
```

The problem is that

```
initgpty = doc.at_xpath("//InitgPty")
```

returns nil so I'm getting a NoMethodError on .add_next_sibling. This is my first time working with both XML and nokogiri but, to me, the XML generated by

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(file_contents)
```

looks very strange. Here's a snippet from what that line outputs in the rails console:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x58d9582 name="InitgPty" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x58ce1be href="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.003.02"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x58d92d0 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x58d9212 name="Nm" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x58ce1be href="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.003.02"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x58d8e84 "B8S Chatter Creators">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x58d8d12 "\n      ">]>
```

Is this correct and the NoMethodError is being caused by something else? Any help at all on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the original XML look like? The `InitgPty` element is in the  `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.003.02` namespace so you may need to include that in your XPath query.

Comment: How about `doc.css('InitgPty').first`?

Comment: @Matt can I use css on an xml document?

Comment: I think so, but you'll have to verify it. If it returns `nil` there is no such element in your XML-document.

Comment: @Matt That seems to be finding the correct element now. It seems like the child element is not getting created correctly but at least I'm finding the correct place. I can debug further from here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I converted it into an answer, feel free to accept it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use CSS selectors. This also works for XML-documents:

```
doc.css('InitgPty').first
#should return the first element named InitgPty
```